# MySQL LIMIT results with INNER JOIN with more than 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, inner-join

I have a database where a user is allowed to have more than one email address. I want to query the database to get all the instances of a job for that customer. Each job is returning twice, one with each email.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT customers.first_name, customers.last_name, emails.email, services.title, services.description, jobs.status, jobs.job_id 
FROM customers 

INNER JOIN emails ON customers.user_id=emails.user_id 
INNER JOIN jobs ON customers.user_id=jobs.customer_id 
INNER JOIN services ON jobs.service_id=services.service_id;
```

It is returning something like this:

[image: database]

I want to return results with the first email only. The row should not be duplicated for each email address the user has on file.

How can this be done?

Comment: Provide your table definitions and some sample data set to test

Comment: What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Have a look @ [*sql fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/) put your tables schema and sample data set here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` on SQL to get unique column value like follows.

```
SELECT customers.first_name, customers.last_name, emails.email, services.title, services.description, jobs.status 
FROM customers 

INNER JOIN emails ON customers.user_id=emails.user_id 
INNER JOIN jobs ON customers.user_id=jobs.customer_id 
INNER JOIN services ON jobs.service_id=services.service_id;

GROUP BY jobs.job_id;
```

Comment: This returns both email addresses for the same job, I want the same email address for both jobs.

Comment: then try the `jobs.status` inside group by. I edit the answer also.

Comment: If I have more than one job with the same status then I don't return the right results.

Comment: better to include job name or job id in the select and place that column name inside the group by.

Comment: good idea, the `job_id` is unique so that should work. What if I wanted to list the other (second in this case) email address, how could I do that?

Comment: unfortunately this is a problem on group by. It will always try to take first occurrence. And there is no direct way to do this. Then you have to go for large block of mysql script with conditions also.